# Pivoting an sql server table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

How to convert a SQL Server table `meterdata` into `Result_Table` using a SQL query?

`MeterData` table stores the power and frequency and has primary key `(meterno, date, timeblock)` and the meterno column has variable no. of values.

**MeterData** table:

```
meterno date      timeblock power   frequency       
--------------------------------------------------
89      1-Apr-16    1       500       50.02     
89      1-Apr-16    2       100       49.99     
90      1-Apr-16    1       200       50.02     
90      1-Apr-16    2       300       49.89
```

**Result_Table**

```
date    timeblock   89_power 90_power   89_frequency 90_frequency   
1-Apr-16    1       500      200        50.02       50.02   
1-Apr-16    2       100      300        49.99       49.89
```

For simplicity lets assume that meterno column has fixed no. of values say (89,90). I am trying the following query but not getting the results. Can someone edit the the query so that the output is Results_Table as above.Also preferably please answer using pivot query. The query is

```
SELECT
*
 FROM
 (
    SELECT
 *
    FROM meterdata  
 ) AS P
PIVOT
(
  sum (power ) FOR meterno IN (89, 90)
) AS pv1 
PIVOT
(
  sum (frequency ) FOR meterno IN (89, 90)
) AS pv2 

GO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dynamic SQL will help you (I used `##MeterData` and `tempdb` you must use your actual table and database names). Will work with any number of columns in source table. Few comments:

- You need to `CAST` or `CONVERT` all columns to one type (I used `nvarchar(10)` in `@p` variable);
- I exclude columns `meterno`, `date`, `timeblock` because there are not used as *parameters* in your dataset;
- You can `PRINT @sql` before executing to see what has been formed to execute.

Here is query:

```
DECLARE @p nvarchar(max), @c nvarchar(max), @s nvarchar(max), @sql nvarchar(max)

--That will get you this:
--,CAST([power] as nvarchar(10)) [power],CAST([frequency] as nvarchar(10)) [frequency]
SELECT @p = (
SELECT ',CAST(' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) + ' as nvarchar(10)) '+ QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME)
FROM tempdb.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'##MeterData' AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ('meterno','date','timeblock')
FOR XML PATH('')
)
--[power],[frequency]
SELECT @c = STUFF((
SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) 
FROM tempdb.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'##MeterData' AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ('meterno','date','timeblock')
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
--[frequency89],[frequency90],[power89],[power90]
SELECT @s = STUFF((
SELECT DISTINCT ','+QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME + CAST(meterno as nvarchar(10)))
FROM ##MeterData m
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT COLUMN_NAME
    FROM tempdb.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'##MeterData' AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ('meterno','date','timeblock')
) as p 
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
--Put it all in dynamic query
SELECT @sql = '
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT  [date],
            timeblock,
            params + CAST(meterno as nvarchar(10)) as params,
            [values]
    FROM (
        SELECT  meterno, 
                [date], 
                timeblock'
                +@p+
                '
        FROM ##MeterData
        ) as p
    UNPIVOT (
        [values] FOR params IN ('+@c+')
    ) as unpvt
) as p2
PIVOT (
    MAX([Values]) FOR params IN ('+@s+')
) as pvt'
--And execute
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Output:

```
date        timeblock   frequency89 frequency90 power89 power90
2016-04-01  1           50.02       50.02       500     200
2016-04-01  2           49.99       49.89       100     300
```

Comment: thanks @gofr1 ,for a brilliant answer. I was trying to accomplish this from last two days and u have solved in just few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pivot query you can try which does not use the SQL Server `PIVOT` operation:

```
SELECT date, timeblock
    SUM(CASE WHEN meterno=89 THEN power     ELSE 0 END) AS meterno-89_power,
    SUM(CASE WHEN meterno=90 THEN power     ELSE 0 END) AS meterno-90_power,
    SUM(CASE WHEN meterno=89 THEN frequency ELSE 0 END) AS meterno-89_frequency,
    SUM(CASE WHEN meterno=90 THEN frequency ELSE 0 END) AS meterno-89_frequency
FROM MeterData
GROUP BY date, timeblock
```

Comment: Thanks Tim for early reply. But I have not earlier mentioned that meterno column is variable i.e it can have any no of values like 89,90,91,95.....

Comment: If `meterno` only has a fixed set of values, then just modify my query accordingly by adding extra `CASE` statements.  If the number of columns be large or variable, then you will need to use dynamic SQL to handle it.

Comment: it is not large but variable.How can i use dynamic sql in this case? i.e. i want readymade query!

Comment: You can try searching Stack Overflow for this solution, it has been answered many times before.